# Remove duplicate rows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

Employee:

| ID | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 143 | Amy | Flowers |
| 245 | Natasha | Smith |
| 365 | John | Alexander |
| 445 | Natasha | Smith |
| 565 | Monica | Withhouse |
| 644 | Amy | Flowers |
| 1023 | Amy | Alexander |

And employee_details:

| ID | Employee_id | Document_numer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 644 | XXXXXXXXX |
| 2 | 245 | XXXXXX |
| 3 | 365 | XXXXXX |

I need to remove duplicate records that are in the Employee table and that are not related to the employee_details table. In the example data, I would like to delete the employee doublet with the id 143 and 445.

And I must admit that I have no idea how to do it.Could you give me a hint?
The base is postgres

Comment: Are `143` and `445` considered duplicates because of these two conditions. 1) The share the same `name` and 2) Of the two records sharing the same names these particular records are not in the `employee_details` table? I'm assuming that's correct since you don't say that `565` should be deleted even though it's not present in the `employee_details` table; in essence it doesn't match criteria 1.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I didn't add important criteria: a duplicate is considered a record with the same 'name' and 'surname' and isn't related to employee_details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the question is already answered I am adding two different answers here using cte.

```
   create table Employee(ID int, Name varchar(50),  Surname varchar(50));
   insert into Employee values(143, 'Amy',  'Flowers');
   insert into Employee values(245, 'Natasha',  'Smith');
   insert into Employee values(365, 'John', 'Alexander');
   insert into Employee values(445, 'Natasha',  'Smith');
   insert into Employee values(565, 'Monica',   'Withhouse');
   insert into Employee values(644, 'Amy',  'Flowers');
   insert into Employee values(1023,    'Amy',  'Alexander');
   
   create table employee_details ( ID int,  Employee_id int, Document_numer varchar(50));
   insert into employee_details values(1,   644,    'XXXXXXXXX');
   insert into employee_details values(2,   245,    'XXXXXX');
   insert into employee_details values(3,   365,    'XXXXXX');
```

Delete query 1:

```
   with duplicate_employees as
   (
     select * , count(id)over(partition by name,surname) duplicate_count from Employee 
   )
   delete from Employee where id in(
   select id from duplicate_employees de
   where duplicate_count >1 
   and not exists
                 (
                   select 1 from employee_details e where e.Employee_id = de.ID
                 )
                 )


   select * from employee
```

Output:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 245 | Natasha | Smith |
| 365 | John | Alexander |
| 565 | Monica | Withhouse |
| 644 | Amy | Flowers |
| 1023 | Amy | Alexander |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ee6171d006d7837e39146f020261dad6)*

Delete query 2:

```
 with cte as 
 (
   Select *, count(*)over(partition by name,surname) duplicate_count,
   (case when  exists
    (
      select 1 from employee_details ed where ed.Employee_id = e.ID
    )
  then 1 else 0 end) exist_in_details
  from Employee e 
 )
 delete from Employee where id in (select id from cte where duplicate_count>1 and exist_in_details=0 )



 select * from Employee
```

Output:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 245 | Natasha | Smith |
| 365 | John | Alexander |
| 565 | Monica | Withhouse |
| 644 | Amy | Flowers |
| 1023 | Amy | Alexander |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c6f7d0c8d2d31a173ee0246e8e8b1966)*

Answer (score 2):

```
Delete from Employee
Where id not in (
   Select Employee_id 
   from employee_details
)
and name in (
  Select name 
  from Employee
  Group by name having count(name) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm sorry because I did not write one thing and didn`t include it in the sample data - a duplicate is considered when the 'name' and 'surname' are the same. Because there may be, for example: Amy Alexander and in your example she will also remove herself.

Comment: If you need to take into account both name and surname, adjust the subquery to  "Select name, surname 
from Employee
Group by name, surname having count(name) > 1"